# Assigning model instance attributes based on a checkbox value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, input

I have a user model that has `stage_name` and `real_name` string attributes. What I'd like to do is in my `_form.hmlt.erb` have a checkbox next to the real name input box that asks, *Real name is stage name?*. If checked then I'd like to assign the real name as the stage name and disable the Stage Name `input box with`real_name` real name now as its value. So far I have:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_field :stage_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :stage_name %> 
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.text_field :real_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :real_name %>

    # Not sure how to bind my model code to this checkbox
    <%= f.checkbox %>
    <%= f.label 'Real name is stage name?' %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
      var $checkbox   = $(this),
          $secondForm =  $("input[type='text']").eq(2);

      if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        $secondForm.attr("disabled", true).val("<%= @user.real_name %>");
      } else {
          $secondForm.attr("disabled", false).val("");
      }
    });
  )};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to create an elegant script based solution, no backend logic required. One very important thing to note is that using the `disabled` attribute for my input box prevented data from being saved. Instead I used `readonly` and set it to `false` when unchecked. The most important takeaway was determining how to keep the checkbox checked/unchecked despite it not being apart of the model. By using the first conditional makes this all possible.

To summarize, when the document loads the script first checks to see if the value of the stage name is equal to the value of the real name. If so the checkbox is checked. Once inside the edit view the click function is used to toggle the state of the real name input value.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :stage_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :stage_name %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :real_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :real_name %>
        <div>
            <%= label_tag 'user_name_check', 'Real Name is Stage Name?' %>
            <%= check_box_tag 'user_name_check' %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :origin %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :origin %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'scripts' %>
```

**_scripts.html.erb**

```
<script>
    $(function() {  
        var $nameCheck = $('#user_name_check'),
            $stageName = $('#user_stage_name'),
            $realName  = $('#user_real_name'),
            $originalVal = $stageName.val();

        // Checks and mirrors user's real name and stage name

        if ($realName.val() == $stageName.val() && $realName.val() != '') 
            $stageName.attr({
              checked:  'checked',
              readonly: 'readonly'
            });
        }

        $nameCheck.click(function() {
            if ($nameCheck.is(':checked')) {
              $stageName.attr('readonly', 'readonly').val($realName.val());
            } else {
                $stageName.attr('readonly', false).val($originalVal).focus();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to assign an attribute accessor in your model.

```
attr_accessor :real_name_is_stage_name
```

This will create a non-persistent attribute in your model which you can check in one of the callbacks, if the value is `1` then set the `real_name = stage_name` for example:

```
before_save do
  if real_name_is_stage_name == "1"
    real_name = stage_name
  end
end
```

Then set the checkbox to interact with the changes you made so that you can send the value of the checkbox to the model as follows:

```
<%= f.check_box :real_name_is_stage_name %>
```

If you do so, in the javascript code you will only need to disable the Stage name `text_field` when the `check_box` is checked and rails will do the rest of the job

**Model.rb**

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name_check
  ## Validation
  ## Callbacks
  before_validation do 
    if self.name_check == "1" and self.stage_name.present? and !self.real_name.present?
      self.real_name = self.stage_name
    end
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :stage_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :stage_name %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :real_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :real_name %>
        <div>
            <%= f.label :name_check, 'Real Name is Stage Name?' %>
            <%= f.check_box :name_check, value: f.obj.real_name.eql?(f.obj.stage_name)? "1" : "0" if f.obj.real_name.present? and f.obj.stage_name.present? %> %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :origin %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :origin %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'scripts' %>
```

**_scripts.html.erb**

```
<script>
    $(function() {  
        var $nameCheck = $('#artist_name_check'),
            $stageName = $('#artist_stage_name'),
            $realName  = $('#artist_real_name'),
            $originalVal = $stageName.val();

        // Checks and mirrors artist's real name and stage name

        if ($nameCheck.is(':checked')) {
            $stageName.attr("readonly", "readonly");
        }

        $nameCheck.click(function() {
            if ($nameCheck.is(":checked")) {
              $stageName.attr("readonly", "readonly").val($realName.val());
            } else {
                $stageName.attr("readonly", false).val($originalVal).focus();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if you are validating the presence of the `stage_name` then add your code in the `before_validation` block instead of `before_save`

Comment: :real_name_is_stage_name's value isn't saving. Added the code above plus permitted `:real_name_is_stage_name` in my controller's user_params method but no luck.

Comment: The value is not supposed to be saved it is only a temporary value that will tell you whether the checkbox is checked or not. Do you validate the presence of the `stage_name`. Can you show me the updated model code?

Comment: What I was looking to do was save that checked value in the event that user wants to edit their page it would show whether they're using their real/stage name. While waiting on your reply I created a possible solution that resulted in creating a `name_check` boolean attribute. I have to ask though is it feasible to create a phyiscal db attribute vs. a virtual attribute?

Comment: If the main functionality of the check box is to match the two fields, you can check whether the two names are equal in your view and set the `check_box` value to `"1"`. As a proof of concept consider this: `<%= f.check_box :real_name_is_stage_name, value= f.obj.real_name.eql?(f.obj.stage_name)? "1" : "0" if f.obj.real_name.present? and f.obj.stage_name.present? %>`

Comment: Would you consider this a better solution to the one I have up now?

Comment: The only problem I am facing with your solution is that you will be using an entire column to check for this condition. This actually depends on the design of your database. If this check is very important to your app then I might consider following your approach, but if it is only used as a flag then you might be considering the virtual attribute idea. The key point here is that if you are going to use the check through out your app then you won't happy checking every time if `stage_name == real_name` before each time you decide to display the users name

Comment: Would you mind refactoring your code based off my answer because while trying to implement what you're explaining I'm running into some errors.

Comment: So far this seems to be working now. Will do some further testing within the next few hours. Before accepting though, there's no way to keep that checkbox check when you go back to edit the user if it was last checked?

Comment: The checkbox is supposed to be checked that is the condition: `f.obj.real_name.eql?(f.obj.stage_name)? "1" : "0" if f.obj.real_name.present? and f.obj.stage_name.present?`

Comment: Hey so I managed to find a way to get this to work without using any backend logic. Let me know what you think.

Comment: It is also a solution, but as I told you if you need to validate the stage_name and the real_name before saving in the database then you need some sort of backend. You have 3 possible solutions now, choose the one the best fits your project